# Run a python script from its icon in linux

Tags: linux, python

May be this question is very basic i googled it but couldn't get a proper answer. I have a python script which when run as "python2.7 mygui.py" in the terminal opens up a gui but now i want to open the gui by double clicking the file icon.

How can it be done ? The python script is written in Pyqt4 and has the shebang line as well.

If it is not possible ? what is another option ? Should i have to install using pyinstaller??

Comment: Which Linux? I can give you the answer for Ubuntu/Nautilus, but that would be a waste of time if you're using something else.

Comment: sry i'm using ubuntu and centos(as well) forgot to mention that @AFH

Comment: usually all that is required is the correct bang-line. can you confirm that it correctly identifies the runtime required? is python3 installed on your system?

Comment: @FrankThomas I use python2.7 and i installed it using anaconda

Comment: I get that your script is designed to use python2.7. my question is, is that the only python runtime installed on your box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu's Nautilus file manager, right-click on **mygui.py** and select **Properties**. Then click on the **Open With** tab. From there you can see the default application, but you can move down to any of the other applications and then press **Set as default**.

If python is not in the list, you can add it by clicking on **Add** and navigating to the python executable (in my system it's in /usr/bin/python, but you can confirm by typing `which python` in a bash terminal). But if it's not in the list, python may not have been installed correctly, so consider reinstalling.